# Extract numbers in array through While and For Loops and avoid duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I am new in Java and I am trying to implement an algorithm that, only using While and For loops, selects six random numbers between 1 and 49, puts them in an array, and prints them. If there are duplicates, the random process should start again and substitute the duplicates with other numbers and, in the end, sort all numbers in the array. The first step was pretty easy and it seems to work:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class RandomArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] arr = new int[6];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = rand.nextInt(50);
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Indeed, I am struggling to think about how to make the to loops work. I tried to create two loops, one of them (i) iterating before j and removing the duplicates but it is not working:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class RandomArray2 {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] arr = new int[6];
        int j = 0;
        while (j < arr.length) {
            j++;
            arr[j] = rand.nextInt(50);
            Arrays.sort(arr, 0, 7);
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
            for (int i = j + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    arr[i] = rand.nextInt(50);
                    Arrays.sort(arr, 0, 7);
                    System.out.println(arr[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
0
11
11
36
44
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out of bounds for length 7
    at RandomArray2.main(RandomArray2.java:29)
```

I am not expecting to get a solution for the problem but I would be thankful for any advice on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The immediate solution to the exception would be to move `j++` to the end of the `while` loop. A better solution would probably be to use a `for` to traverse the array instead of a `while`. Also, the sorting should probably happen *after* the outer loop, not inside of it.

Comment: *selects six random numbers* - why do you have an array of 7?

Comment: Another thing you may want to do is to change the inner loop so that it checks from 0 to `j`. Otherwise you're checking for duplicates in an area of the array you haven't initialized yet, which will count as a duplicate only if `arr[j]` is 0.

Comment: "7" was an oversight, I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is to check for duplicate before adding to array.

Generating a new random instead of duplicate cannot guarantee that is not duplicate per all array.

Eq: (1,1,2) but and if regenerate 1 and will be 2 then (1,2,2) is not valid.

```
public class RandomArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] arr = new int[7];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int random = rand.nextInt(50);
            //check previous values in order to add only distinct
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (random == arr[j]) {
                    System.out.println("arr[" + j + "]=" + random +
                            " ... compute new one for arr[" + i + "]");
                    random = rand.nextInt(50);
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
            arr[i] = random;
        }
        System.out.println("### Initial");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }

        Arrays.sort(arr);
        System.out.println("### Sorted");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Possible Output:

```
arr[0]=1 ... compute new one for arr[3]
arr[2]=42 ... compute new one for arr[6]
### Initial
1
3
42
12
44
6
32
### Sorted
1
3
6
12
32
42
44
```

Comment: In order to skip 0 it's better to adjust random to be in interval. `random=1+rand.nextInt(49)` , `1+[0-48]`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know if a array contains an element, you should use `myList.contains(3)`. It returns a boolean.